# how to make a T-Test in R in GDS files?

Tags: r

My project is about predicting biomarker breast cancer.

I use this function to give me a 2x2 matrix:

```
Table(gpl96)[1:10,1:4]
```

I want to take this data that represents the samples of genes in GDS and compare the p-value to know if it is normally distributed or not.

Comment: you should add some information about to the question. not all people here are familiar with GDS files? I guess you uses `geoQuery` here from `bioconductor`...

Answer (score 0):

`t.test` tests whether there is a difference in location between two samples that adhere to normal distributions.

To approximately check the assumed normality, you might inspect whether outputs from `qqnorm` seem linear, or use `ks.test` in conjunction with estimating parameters from observations*:

```
set.seed(1)
x1 <- rnorm(200,40,10) # should follow a normal distribution
ks.test(x1,"pnorm",mean=mean(x1),sd=sd(x1)) # p: 0.647 [qqnorm(x1) looks linear]
x2 <- rexp(200,10) # should *not* follow a normal distribution
ks.test(x2,"pnorm",mean=mean(x2),sd=sd(x2)) # p: 3.576e-05, [qqnorm(x2) seems curved]
```

I do not know GEO's `Table`, but I suggest you might want to use its `VALUE` columns -and not any 2x2 matrices- as inputs for `t.test`, `qqnorm` or `ks.test`; maybe you might provide some additional illustration of your data by posting outputs of `head(Table(gpl96)[1:10,1:4])`.

(* After https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-October/040692.html, which also appears to demonstrate the more refined Lilliefors test.)